# NoMethodError undefined method when trying to save field of a child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller, has-many

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with a PostGre database.  I have an object that has several member objects.  In my app/models/my_object.rb file, I have

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :my_object_times
  has_one :address
  attr_accessor :hour, :minute, :second

  validates_numericality_of :overall_rank, :age_rank, :gender_rank

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :my_object_times
end
```

Then in my view, I have this in my form …

```
  <%= f.fields_for :my_object_times do |rt| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= rt.label :overall_rank %><br>
    <%= rt.text_field :overall_rank %>
  </div>
```

but I get this error when submitting my form

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `overall_rank' for #<MyObject:0x007fd66df43968>):
  app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb:10:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

I don’t understand why I’m getting this error.  Below is my app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb file

```
class MyObjectsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
    @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    @my_object.user = @current_user
    @date = Date.strptime(my_object_params[:day], "%m/%d/%Y")
    @my_object.day = @date
    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_object.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Saved successfully' 
        format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
        format.js { render js: "window.location='/users'" }
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
        format.js   { render json: @my_object.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help is appreciated, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

While there is no code for your `my_object_params` private method, maybe you miss `overall_rank` in it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the action of which the view is for, but according to your controller code I am assuming that you are trying to create a new object. In other words, the html code is for the new action.

When generating the form, you are calling `my_object_times` inside of the object, but it still does not exist.

```
<%= f.fields_for :my_object_times do |rt| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= rt.label :overall_rank %><br>
    <%= rt.text_field :overall_rank %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```